# How to deserialiaze json files from a website directory in java

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have to deserialize json files from a website directory which hold x number of json files. The directory looks as follows: first when you open the directory you have different maps with city names. Inside those maps you have another submap called dynamic or a json file with all the parking places for a city. If it is the first one you have inside the dynamic map x amount of files named by the identifier of the parking place.

What I have to do is deserialize all those json files and map it all to a java object. Below you can see an example of such a json file:

```
        { "parkingFacilityDynamicInformation": { 
            "description":"",
            "identifier":"257938b9-2a30-443b-8ad",
            "name":"Parking Garage",
            "facilityActualStatus": { 
                "full":false,
                "lastUpdated":1576076774,
                "open":false,
                "statusDescription":"Closed",
                "parkingCapacity":399,
                "vacantSpaces":229
            }
        }
        }
```

Could someone maybe give me a suggestion on where to look for a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are [a lot](https://www.baeldung.com/java-json) of libraries to choose from, one of the most popular being [`Jackson`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization). After creating the Java model, deserialization can be as easy as `new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyModel.class)`.

Comment: I know about different ways to deserialize normal json files. But I don't know how to deserialize when you have a directory with all the json files instead of just a json file.

Comment: You could iterate over the directories files and deserialize one by one using the ObjectMappers `public <T> T readValue(File src, Class<T> valueType)` method.